# System.Directory Services not supported on windows platform

Tags: c#, .net, windows, directoryservices

i am quite new to software development as well as to this site.
My question is about the System.DirectoryServices development on windows.
I started a normal Visual Studio 2019 c# .net 5.0 project and added the references for the .dll file as well as the nuget packages for it and even the windows compatibility package.
I also changed the target framework from .net5.0 to .net5.0-windows, but it still says "System.DirectoryServices is not supported on this platform"
Every time i try to create a DirectoryEntry it gives me the mentioned message above.

Following my Code to generate a User:

```
try
            {
                DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
                DirectoryEntry NewUser = AD.Children.Add(du.Name, "user");
                NewUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { du.password });
                NewUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "Description", "Test User from .NET" });
                NewUser.CommitChanges();
                DirectoryEntry grp;

                grp = AD.Children.Find("Administrators", "group");
                if (grp != null) { grp.Invoke("Add", new object[] { NewUser.Path.ToString() }); }
                Console.WriteLine("Account Created Successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

Can someone help me?
My goal is to simply create a new local user on a windows system.

Thank you very much in advance!

I followed the ideas mentioned here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/853176/systemplatformnotsupportedexception-systemdirector.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay apparently my problem is just as simple as it is...
As mentioned i am quite new..
"System.DirectoryService" is not supported on this platform means, that the framework version i am developing on does not support the .dll i was importing.

The solution:
I installed VS2022, started a new project with 6.0 .net framework and loaded the nuget packages for "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" & "System.DirectoryServices.Protocols" and now it works fine.

Comment: Had a similar issue here, with project X referencing project Y (DLL reference). Only project Y referenced AD. Project X compiled but was throwing _System.DirectoryServices is not supported on this platform_ until I added `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` package to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to make it work with `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` v6.0.0 on .NET Core 5.0. Unfortunately, at this time, I cannot upgrade to Visual Studio 2022, which supports .NET 6.0 and above.

Comment: .NET 5 reached End Of Life a long time ago. .NET 6 is the oldest supported version. You don't need Visual Studio to use .NET Core